# LOAD DATA INFILE only Loads 0s, NULLs, and Blanks

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I am trying to load a .csv file into a mysql database using the following code:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/mytestfile.csv' INTO TABLE report.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(ONE, TWO)
```

The .csv file looks like:

```
ONE,TWO
1,2
```

And the two columns in report.test are both integers.

When I run the SQL code, I get the the both values in the first row of report.test are 0s.  When I run this on my actual .csv file, only a fraction of the rows are read, and they are populated by 0s, NULLs, and Blanks.

Am I missing a setting somewhere?

---

UPDATE 1 - I dont have enough reputation to post pictures, so I had to do links.

[Table Structure](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHYMGRQ_V0bcXFIRkUwUWcyX3c/edit?usp=sharing)

[Example File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHYMGRQ_V0bbjVMUzByc3dXaTg/edit?usp=sharing)

---

UPDATE 2

When I use:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

The warnings are :

```
'Warning','1366','Incorrect integer value: \'??\' for column \'ONE\' at row 1'
'Warning','1366','Incorrect integer value: \'??\' for column \'TWO\' at row 1'
'Warning','1262','Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns'
```

When I use:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The warnings are :

```
'Warning','1366','Incorrect integer value: \'??\' for column \'ONE\' at row 1'
'Warning','1366','Incorrect integer value: \'??\' for column \'TWO\' at row 1'
'Warning','1262','Row 1 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns'
'Warning','1366','Incorrect integer value: \'?\' for column \'ONE\' at row 2'
'Warning','1261','Row 2 doesn\'t contain data for all columns'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL statement looks fine.

It adds 0s in the first row because you're adding the column headers too. To ignore the first line use `IGNORE 1 LINES`.

The only reason I can think of why you're having problems is because of the file that doesn't have carriage return.

Please test with the following statement:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/mytestfile.csv' INTO TABLE report.test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(ONE, TWO)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  That still just brings in 0s.

Comment: Can you add your actual table structure and a sample of the csv file ?

Comment: Any other ideas?  I've tried playing with the different line terminations and table structures and nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I just run in my local machine and it worked with no problems. What MySQL version are you using ? I'll download the version you're using and test on Windows too. Actually, after you run the query, send the command "SHOW WARNINGS", see if it shows anything, it might help you to identify what's wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am using MySQL 5.5.24, MySQL Community Server (GPL).  I have phpMyAdmin running and also use MySQL Workbench. I'll put the warnings in the original post.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what is causing that, but accordingly the warning messages it seems mysql it not reading your file properly. Maybe the file is using an encoding different from your server. I'm not sure about that, but I believe if the file enconding is different from the serve, you need to definite using "CHARACTER SET" in the SQL statement. Check how is used in the manual. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

Comment: That was it!  I used the "CHARACTER SET" and everything is working perfectly now.  Thank you so much!